# Angular UI Router's $stateChangeSuccess not being emitted after switching to using Browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, browserify

I have an Angular 1.5.x application that uses Angular UI Router's `$stateChangeSuccess` event to register a listener that verifies if a user is logged in on each state change to protect certain views of the application. After porting the application into a CommonJS environment via Browserify, the registered event handlers do not execute any more, but UI Router keeps changing states as previously. I need help figuring out if and why UI Router is not emitting the event or if the problem is being caused by Angular scopes behaving differently when working in a CommonJS environment. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

### EDIT

I had angular-ui-router 1.0.0-alpha.1 installed via npm. I checked out the angular ui router github releases docs based on Chris's comment and decided to see if it worked by reverting to 0.2.18, it didn't.

### app.js

The only require statements of relevance are the routes, core, and services modules.

```
'use strict';

var angular = require('angular');

var routes = require('./app.routes.js');

// Sub-module Dependencies 
var core       = require('./app.core.js');
var services   = require('./services');
var layout     = require('./layout');
var auth       = require('./authentication');
var landing    = require('./landing');
var dashboard  = require('./dashboard');
var userManual = require('./user-manual');

// Define Angular Module
var app = angular.module('app', [
  core,
  services,
  layout,
  auth,
  landing,
  dashboard,
  userManual
])
.config(html5ModeTrue)
.config(routes)
.run(runBlock);

////////////////

html5ModeTrue.$inject = ['$locationProvider'];
runBlock.$inject = ['authService'];

////////////////

function html5ModeTrue ($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}

function runBlock(authService) {
  authService.initialize();
}
```

### app.routes.js

```
'use strict';

routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

function routes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
  $urlRouterProvider.when('/dashboard', '/dashboard/analysis');
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: "app/landing/home.html"
    })
    .state('about', {
      url: "/about",
      templateUrl: "app/landing/about.html"
    })
    .state('atlas', {
      url: "/atlas",
      templateUrl: "app/landing/atlas.html"
    })
    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: "app/authentication/login.html",
      controller: "LoginController",
      controllerAs: "login"
    })
    .state('dashboard', {
      abstract: true,
      // url: "/dashboard",
      templateUrl: "app/dashboard/dashboard.html",
      controller: "DashboardController",
      controllerAs: "dash",
      restricted: true,
    })
    .state('dashboard.analysis', {
      url: "/dashboard/analysis",
      templateUrl: "app/dashboard/dashboard.analysis.html"
    })
    .state('dashboard.vmod', {
      url: "/dashboard/vmod",
      templateUrl: "app/dashboard/dashboard.vmod.html"
    })
    .state('dashboard.datasets', {
      url: "/dashboard/datasets",
      templateUrl: "app/dashboard/dashboard.datasets.html"
    })
    .state('dashboard.defaults', {
      url: "/dashboard/defaults",
      templateUrl: "app/dashboard/dashboard.defaults.html"
    })
    .state('dashboard.user-management', {
      url: "/dashboard/user-management",
      templateUrl: "app/dashboard/dashboard.user-management.html"
    })
    .state('user-manual', {
      url: "/user-manual",
      templateUrl: "app/user-manual/user-manual.html",
      restricted: true
    })
    .state('user-manual.analysis', {})
    .state('user-manual.vmod', {})
    .state('user-manual.datasets', {});
}

module.exports = routes;
```

### app.core.js

As shown below, angular-ui-router, which was installed via npm, is being required into the core dependencies submodule of the application

```
'use strict';

// Module Dependencies
require('angular-animate');       // ngAnimate
require('angular-ui-bootstrap');  // ui.bootstrap
require('angular-ui-router');     // ui.router
require('ui-leaflet');            // ui-leaflet
require('leaflet');               // Dependency for ui-leaflet
require('angular-simple-logger'); // Dependency for ui-leaflet

// Define Angular Module
var name = 'app.core';
require('angular').module(name, [
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'ui.router',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ui-leaflet',
]);

// Expose Angular Module Name For Easy Injection
module.exports = name;
```

### services/index.js

This file simply serves as the entry point for the requiring the application's Angular services.

```
'use strict';

// Module Dependencies
var authService = require('./auth.service.js');
var userManagementService = require('./user-management.service.js');

// Define Angular Module
var name = 'app.services';
require('angular')
  .module(name, [])
  .factory('authService', authService)
  .factory('userManagementService', userManagementService);

module.exports = name;
```

### services/auth.service.js

The initialize function in this service registers a listener to the `$stateChangeSuccess` event, which never gets called.

```
'use strict';

authService.$inject = ['$q', '$window', '$http', '$rootScope', '$location'];

function authService ($q, $window, $http, $rootScope, $location) {
  var userSession = null;

  var service = {
    initialize: initialize,
    isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
    getUserSession: getUserSession,
    login: login,
    logout: logout
  };
  return service;

  ////////////////

  function initialize() {
    var accessToken = $window.sessionStorage["fa-session"];
    userSession = accessToken ? JSON.parse(accessToken) : null;
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', onStateChangeSuccess);

    function onStateChangeSuccess(event, toState, fromState, fromParams) {
      if (toState.restricted && isLoggedIn() === false) {
        $location.path('/login');
      }
    }
  }

  function isLoggedIn() {
    return userSession || false;
  }

  function getUserSession() {
    return userSession;
  }

  function login(username, password) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post('/api/login', {username: username, password: password})
      .then(loginComplete)
      .catch(loginFailed);
    return deferred.promise;

    function loginComplete(response) {
      userSession = {
        accessToken: response.data.access_token,
        username: response.data.username
      };
      $window.sessionStorage["fa-session"] = JSON.stringify(userSession);
      deferred.resolve(userSession);
    }

    function loginFailed(error) {
      deferred.reject(error);
    }
  }

  function logout() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post('/api/logout', {headers: {access_token: userSession.accessToken}})
      .then(logoutCompleted)
      .catch(logoutFailed);
    return deferred.promise;

    function logoutCompleted(response) {
      userSession = null;
      $window.sessionStorage["fa-session"] = null;
      deferred.resolve(response);
    }

    function logoutFailed(error) {
      deferred.reject(error);
    }
  }
}
module.exports = authService;
```

Comment: "angular-ui-router, which was installed via npm"  What version of ui-router is it?  In the 1.0.0 alpha releases, we've deprecated the $stateChange events in favor of $transitions.on* hooks.  You can re-add the deprecated events to ui-router 1.0.0 by including angular-ui-router/release/stateEvents.js file.

Comment: I have 1.0.0 alpha 1. In my package.json I have the following line:
    "angular-ui-router": "^1.0.0-alpha.1"

As for the $transitions.on* hooks, I'd like to learn more about them. If $stateChange events are indeed deprecated, I don't want to stay behind.

Comment: @ChrisT : it would be nice to have the docs updated, I think a lot of users have used `$stateChange` events, as all the tutorials on the internet says so.https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events. I don't find doc on $transition neither

Comment: Alpha.3 transition hook docs: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/1.0.0-alpha.3/interfaces/transition.ihookregistry.html#onstart and state event docs: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/1.0.0-alpha.3/modules/ng1_state_events.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to get it working by using the $transition.on* hooks Chris T mentioned in his comment. I also investigated if this $rootScope problem was occurring outside of the state change events. From what I was able to verify, $scope and $rootScope event emitters and handlers worked perfectly fine with my controllers.

### I changed this:

```
.state('user-manual', {
  url: "/user-manual",
  templateUrl: "app/user-manual/user-manual.html",
  restricted: true
})
```

### Into this, where the restricted property was used by the even listener inside of authService:

```
.state('user-manual', {
  url: "/user-manual",
  templateUrl: "app/user-manual/user-manual.html",
  // restricted: true
  onEnter: function (authService, $location) {
    if (!authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      $location.path('/login');
    }
  }
})
```